# Is it possible using copy() php function for different domain?

Tags: php

Does anyone knows if is it possible using copy() function in php but in different domain?

I already read [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_copy.asp) and that copy() function work if file directory in 1 domain,

```
 echo copy("source.txt","target.txt");
```

but what if a file exist in another domain? 
example

```
echo copy("http://www.websample.com/source.txt","http://www.anotherdomain.com/target.txt");
```

or anyone have another method? thanks

Comment: you can use curl for different domain, if you have permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No** (if you don't own/control the destination url)

You cant copy your stuff to someone else's server without them providing you an interface for it or you finding a loophole to crack their server.

**Yes** If the destination url/server is in your control you can enable `fopen wrappers`

> Both source and dest may now be URLs if the "fopen wrappers" have been enabled. See [fopen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) for more details.

And you also have to ensure this

> The destination path. **If dest is a URL, the copy operation may fail if the wrapper does not support overwriting of existing files.**

**[Manual](http://php.net/copy)**